# Update multiple fields in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 table. I want to update `table 1(Home_Archive)` based on `table 2(Home)`. 
Both table have `home_id` field.
I want to update multiple field with this query but it does not work. Error said it has MySQL syntax error. I thought the syntax is correct.

```
UPDATE Home_Archive 
SET 
t1.name = t2.name,
t1.price = t2.price,
t1.area = t2.area
FROM 
Home_Archive t1 
INNER JOIN Home t2 ON  t1.home_id = t2.home_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE Home_Archive ha JOIN
       Home h
       ON ha.home_id = h.home_id
SET ha.name = h.name,
    ha.price = h.price,
    ha.area = h.area;
```

There is no `FROM` clause.  The `JOIN` is part of the `UPDATE`.